# Why does Lorenzo de Medici never ask about his daughters?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, da-vincis-demons

Recently I watched series named [Da Vinci's Demons](http://imdb.com/rg/an_share/title/title/tt2094262/), and this question is about the character [Lorenzo de Medici](http://davincisdemons.wikia.com/wiki/Lorenzo_de%27_Medici)

In one episode in season 3 (I don't remember the episode) he was caught by the Turks and was eventually able to escape from their prison. He returned to Florence (he is the ruler of this city) and learned that his wife is dead. He mourns for days but he takes control of the city as true a ruler and makes some important decisions.

What I'm curious about is that he has three daughters and never asks anyone where they are (they're sent to some other place safe by their mother while Lorenzo was in prison).

My question: is Lorenzo being rude to not ask about the whereabouts of his daughters after returning home, or did the writers just forget about them?

Comment: Given that the show is a *historical-fiction* about based on the lives of various italian nobles, is there a) Any reason to assume that they wrote him as having daughters and B) Any reason to assume that he didn't just ask about them when the cameras weren't on him.

Comment: If they don't show this on camera it will directly effect to character of lorenzo de medici in context of this series . Of course that is my thought though. If they show only two dialogue conversation like " where are my daughter ?" " they are safe ". It will enough

Comment: They probably thought that was irrelevant. Given that the show ended suddenly and the last season was totally shabby, it looks like they were just trying to put all the pieces together and be done with it. In such a rush, his daughters who were insignificant to the plot were ignored.